# MySQL 5.7 on Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS does not recognize any configuration-variable

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, mysql-replication

I am trying to create a master-master replication between two databases, one being an RDS instance with MySQL 5.6.44 on AWS the other one being on an Ubuntu-Server running MySQL 5.7 (I was unable to install 5.6) by creating a slave replication in both directions as shown [here](https://ittutorial.org/mysql-master-to-master-replication/). This is an attempt to evade [problems occuring when using two RDS instances for a master-master-topology](https://serverfault.com/questions/1029110/aws-rds-mysql-rds-set-external-master-remains-disabled-after-setting-autocommit).

However, mysql on the Ubuntu-Server fails to recognise every configuration variable provided in /etc/mysql/my.cnf with `[ERROR] unknown variable 'server-id=8'`, thus I am unable to configure this instance as a replication-master. Adding whitespaces between the variable name, = and the value did not solve the problem.

Any help to solve this is highly appreciated.

**my.cnf:**

```
[mysql]
server-id=8
replicate-same-server-id=0
auto-increment-increment=2
auto-increment-offset=1
relay-log-index=serverB-relay-bin.index
master-info-file=mysqk-master.info
relay-log-info-file=serverB-relay-log.info
log-bin=mysql-bin
log-error=/var/log/mysql/err
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All of those should be after this tag:

```
[mysqld]
```

The tag `[mysql]` refers to the commandline tool, not the server.